# Append page to id in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have created a template **authorPageTemplate** which is a page with id **author + id** upon clicking the image on the galley i want to append the author page using the template.

page template function is

```
var authorPageTemplate = function(id){
var authorPage = '<div data-role="page" id="author' + id +'">';
    authorPage += '<div id="content-pane'></div>;
    authorPage += '</div>';
    return authorPage;
}


$("#page5").on("pageshow", function(event){
    $("#gallery a").on("tap", function(){
    idNum = $(this).attr("id");
    setID(idNum);
    $("#container").append(authorPageTemplate(getID()));
    $.mobile.changePage("#author" + getID(), {
        transistion : "slidefade"
    });
});
});
```

now i also added another code to update the content-pane of the author page that is created

```
$("#author" + getID()).on("pageshow", function(event){
    $("#author" + getID() + " #content-pane").html(updateHtml(getID()));
});
```

problem: 
1. author page is not created.

Comment: what version of jQM are you using? What id $("#container")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/C3X85/)**

Your template code has some problems with the single quotes and double quotes near id="content-plane' and the ending /div. It should look like this:

```
function authorPageTemplate(id){
    var authorPage = '<div data-role="page" id="author' + id +'">';
    authorPage += '<div id="content-pane"></div>';
    authorPage += '</div>';
    return authorPage;
}
```

Then in your pageshow, use $(document).on("pageshow", "#author" +"num1", function(event){...
which allows the handler to exist before the page is created.  The handler will be delegated from the document to the dynamic page.

```
$(document).on("pageshow", "#page5", function(){
    $("#gallery a").on("click", function(){
        $("body").append(authorPageTemplate('num1'));
        $.mobile.changePage("#author" + "num1", {
            transistion : "slidefade"
        });
    });

    $(document).on("pageshow", "#author" +"num1", function(event){
        $("#author" + "num1" + " #content-pane").html('I am a dynamic page');
    });
});
```